# Linux display currently running processes

Tags: linux

What is the command to display currently running processes and the option to display PPID's?

I thought that it might be:

jobs -p

jobs -pl

Neither worked though. Any hints?

Comment: for getting one using your username: `top -u username` idk how to do it with ps but that would be nice to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ps -ef` will display all processes and include PPIDs.

Comment: ps -f gave me the answer I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on what you're after

you usually use

```
top
```

to see how processes consume system resources

however, if you just want to see some process pid, and know some word from the command that used to run it, try:

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

there are other (many) commands and tools, it really depends on the reason you look for the process

Answer (score -1):

for getting one using your username: `top -u username` idk how to do it with ps but that would be nice to know.